# How to erase the drawing on image

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw on image in android. I found one good example from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-essential-functionality--mobile-19328).
Here they explained how to draw in the plain canvas. I tried to add image in that canvas.

```
canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image)
                .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(canvasBitmap, this.getWidth(),
                this.getHeight(), true);
```

Now I am facing one issue. When I try to erase the drawings it erase the original image also.

I tried lots of solution. But nothing helps me. Please let me know how to erase the drawings in the image without erase the Image.

Comment: The behaviour is so normal! You can try to use a real pen and draw on your photo, next you try to remove that with an eraser and see what happen.

Comment: Your question is that you want the original image to stay intact after erasing your "custom" drawing?

Comment: Yes @RomanRozenshtein.. Exactly what you say that I want..

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is to just draw the image back onto Canvas. Over everything else.

This would leave you with just the origional image -> Drawings removed.